# How to make application rotate in AVD

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, screen-rotation

This is for a school project, but i didn't understand many parts of this.

I am leaving the handling of the rotation to the system, but after describing 2 layouts (standart and landscape mode)
But the landscape mode layout won't be taken into account when I rotate the screen.

[image]
<sub>(source: [hostingpics.net](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/647131Capturedu20160327204339.png))</sub>

(I have pressed the 4th button, in case it is the issue ...)

The mainactivity extends `AppCompatActivity`, (Because our teacher told us to), and all I do (for now) in the MainActivity is

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d(TAG,"Test");
}
```

then I described 2 LinearLayouts, one in layout/activity_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:divider="@drawable/empty_divider_tall"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:background="@color/fl_concrete"
    >

    <fragment
        class="com.example.g20901528.androidproject.fragment.TopFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_top"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />

    <fragment
        class="com.example.g20901528.androidproject.fragment.BottomFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />



</LinearLayout>
```

and another in layout-land/activity-main.xml which is almost the same :
edit : layout-land/activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:divider="@drawable/empty_divider_wide"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:background="@color/fl_concrete"

    >
    <fragment
        class="com.example.g20901528.androidproject.fragment.TopFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_top"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />

    <fragment
        class="com.example.g20901528.androidproject.fragment.BottomFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />



</LinearLayout>
```

I did not change my manifest aside describing the MainActivity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.g20901528.androidproject">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

My question is : how to make it so the two fragments rotate when i rotate the phone ?

I'm ready to provide any information.

[Github Link of the project](https://github.com/GPierre-Antoine/AndroidProject), if you really need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dude your layout xml name is different please change that
layout/activity_main.xml

> layout-land/activity-main.xml make it -->
>   layout-land/activity_main.xml

and run

Comment: it is a good point indeed, unfortunately, it was activity_main.xml in both in my filesystem.